# Error posting record to db asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, fullcalendar

I am building a scheduling system using fullcalendar for MVC, my get event retrieves from a view for a specific location.
However, my post / save event inserts into the table that the view is made from, containing all locations.

I am getting an error when I try to add the new event to the data connection.

> "The field Location must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '1'."  string
>   PropertyName    "Location"  string

I tried to set the string for the event manually before adding it to the data connection but this isn't working for some reason. Could it be me not declaring the string correctly?

```
//Actions for Calendar 5
public JsonResult GetEvents5()
{
    using (CalgaryNEEntities dc = new CalgaryNEEntities())
    {
        var events = dc.CalgaryNEEvents.ToList();
        return new JsonResult { Data = events, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveEvent5(EventsAllLocation e)
{
    var status = false;
    using (InsertEntities dc = new InsertEntities())
    {
        if (e.EventID > 0)
        {
            //Update the event
            var v = dc.EventsAllLocations.Where(a => a.EventID == e.EventID).FirstOrDefault();
            if (v != null)
            {
                var locationstring = "Calgary NE Kitchens";
                v.CompanyName = e.CompanyName;
                v.Start = e.Start;
                v.End = e.End;
                v.KitchenNumber = e.KitchenNumber;
                v.Location = locationstring;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var locationstring = "Calgary NE Kitchens";
            e.Location = locationstring;
            dc.EventsAllLocations.Add(e);
        }

        dc.SaveChanges();
        status = true;

    }
    return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status } };
}
```

Here is the EventsAllLocation definition:

```
public partial class EventsAllLocation
{
    public int EventID { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> End { get; set; }
    public string KitchenNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Any tips or help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The error seems to say that `Location` has a max length of 1 character. You might check the table definition to see if it really can only be 1 character long. That seems like a mistake.

Comment: My god, complete brain fart, i misread as minimum length of 1, thanks for pointing out :) .... Maybe i should take a nap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is staring you in the face !! LOL

> "The field Location must be a string or array type with a **maximum**
>   length of '1'." string PropertyName "Location" string